# How to get genre info using Dbpedia ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, screen-scraping, wikipedia, dbpedia

I am trying to fetch artist info from wikipedia using Dbpedia gem https://github.com/farbenmeer/dbpedia

But I am unable to figure out what is the genre of a result item.

Basically I want to modify following function to find out which result is an artist and then return its url:

```
  def self.get_slug(q)
    results = Dbpedia.search(q)
    result  = # Do something to find out the result that is an artist
    uri   = result.uri rescue ""
    return uri
  end
```

The last resort will be for me to scrape each result url and then find out if it is an artist or not based on if there is genre info available.

Comment: I am confused, do you want to find the genre of an item or figure out whether an item is an artist? Those two don't seem to be the same thing to me at all. Also, adding some examples to your question could help.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was not very clear. I am trying to handle a situation where there are multiple results for a search. I want to only return a result that has genre information available on it.

Comment: @whizcreed: Do you need the URI for the search results?

Comment: @AnkitG yes, uri of the search result that has genre info would work perfectly.. thanks.

Comment: can you please tell what would you exactly search for to get genre? I mean the query?

Comment: @Surya: sure, if you search for aina on wikipedia you will get this url: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aina, this page includes multiple links. one of them is for the band: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aina_(band) if you go to this url then you will see that there is genres info available since it is related to music. So I want this function to fetch details via dbpedia gem and filter out one or more results which would have genre info available.

Comment: I am sorry, but I thought that you're querying for just artists. From your comment it looks like you're looking for a scrapper which scrap each link and links inside other links till it finds genre? Then scrapper script has to be more smart to pickup band, artists, songs, music, etc keywords to scrap the next page and fetch genre. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could leverage from [DBpedia's](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess?v=17is) [SPARQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL) endpoint, rather than scrapping over all results.

Suppose you want a list of everything that has a `genre`. You could query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?thing WHERE {
  ?thing dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre
}
LIMIT 1000
```

But say you don't want *everything*, you're looking just for artists. It could be a musician, a painter, an actor, etc.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?thing WHERE {
  ?thing dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre ;
         rdf:type          dbpedia-owl:Artist

}
LIMIT 1000
```

Or maybe you just want musicians **OR** bands:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?thing WHERE {
  {
    ?thing dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre ;
           rdf:type          dbpedia-owl:Band
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?thing dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre ;
           a                 dbpedia-owl:MusicalArtist # `a` is a shortcut for `rdf:type`
  } 
}
LIMIT 1000
```

Ultimately, you want musicians or bands that have "mega" in their names, e.g. Megadeath or Megan White, along with the URL of the resource.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?thing, ?url, ?genre WHERE {
  ?thing foaf:name             ?name ;
         foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url .
  ?name  bif:contains "'mega*'" .
  {
    ?thing dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre ;
           a                 dbpedia-owl:Band
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?thing dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre ;
           a                 dbpedia-owl:MusicalArtist
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?thing a <http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/MusicalPerformer>
  }
}
LIMIT 1000
```

Give it a try to this queries using the [DBpedia's SPARQL Query Editor](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).

The [dbpedia gem](https://github.com/farbenmeer/dbpedia) you pointed out, reveals the [sparql-client](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/sparql-client) in its API. So, I think you will be able to run all this queries using the [`#query`](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/sparql-client#executing-an-arbitrary-textual-sparql-query-string) method

```
Dbpedia.sparql.query(query_string)
```

Best luck!

Comment: sorry I was away for a while.. Could you also show me how I could get the url of the result?

Comment: Apparently the URL of the resource is in the `foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf` property. I've updated the answer to show that as well. You might want to increase the execution timeout, e.g. 60000ms, in case you're getting blank results from the query editor.

Comment: I am not sure why, but when I try to look for Shakira I am not getting the right result.. You can try out the query below:
SELECT DISTINCT ?thing, ?url WHERE { ?thing foaf:name    ?name ;   foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url . ?name bif:contains "'shakira*'" . {  ?thing dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre ;    a     dbpedia-owl:Band } UNION {  ?thing dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre ;    a     dbpedia-owl:MusicalArtist } } LIMIT 1000

Comment: Shakira's entry isn't categorized as `a dbpedia-owl:MusicalArtist`, but as `umbel MusicalPerformer`. If you add `UNION { ?thing a <http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/MusicalPerformer> }` to the search conditions, it will return the expected result.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying quickly.. just one last thing, if you could also show me how to select genres, just like u selected the url. It would be great if you could update the answer for both the things, MusicalPerformer and genre info. I will immediately accept your answer and award you the bounty. I must say you are really good with this thing, and you have surely saved me a lot of time. Thanks :)

Comment: There you go, answer updated. Mind that when the artist has no genre set, the value for this will be blank. And when it has more than one, it will have multiple entries with the values for `thing` and `url` repeated (just like a SQL join), so you will have to group them manually. Examples for both scenarios are search results for `Shakira` (no genre set) and `Megadeth` (3 genres set), respectively.

Comment: Hi @wicz, The dbpedia service keeps going down from time to time. can you suggest some work around for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. As a last resource you could try setting up your own [mirror](https://github.com/dbpedia/dbpedia-live-mirror).

Comment: Hey need a little more help. Your query works great, just that when I search for James brown, I don't get any results but when I search for James I get many results which includes James brown as well. I am really close to finishing this app and I really appreciate your help.